# Нарисовать график

Tags: графика, график

Друзья, добрый день! Столкнулся с проблемой при создании графика. Не могу понять где возможно нарисовать что-то подобное[image: введите сюда описание изображения]? В экселе есть возможность нарисовать либо один график, либо одни точки. Может есть какая-нибудь программа умнее экселя в данном вопросе? Подскажите, кто знает, пожалуйста))

Comment: конечно есть D3.js, SVG и в конце концов просто векторные редакторы

Comment: найти спеца по javascrpt он и без всяких эксцелей и svg сделает это на js - возьмите спеца по css так он тоже это нарисует на css